# A less costly alternative to indexed views?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, clustered-index, sql-view

I like the idea of materialized (I guess that's the Oracle term) or indexed (Microsoft's term) views [for all the performance benefits listed in this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921(v=sql.100).aspx), and dislike them for the costs associated with index upkeep that must occur on updates (also mentioned in the article).

So, my query I'm trying to optimize is currently putting it's results into a @ActiveCustomers table variable, which gets used in an even larger query.. anyways, it contains numerous complex joins - so many that I think it would be nice to just dump it's results into a new static table.

The problem with a new static table, of course, is that it's completely disconnected from it's source tables. The data in my "@ActiveCustomers" table variable, for the purposes of my particular report, need not be "bleeding-edge current", it just needs to be "a few hours ago accurate".

Is there some in-between solution - like, an indexed view that only gets it's index(es) "maintained" at a scheduled interval that I control?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to analyse your data. Have you consider SQL Server Analysis Services?

Comment: You could create an SSIS job to refresh the static table, and run it via SQL Agent once every couple hours.

Comment: I have an custom MVC web app that needs to render a System.Data.DataSet on demand (think of my MVC app being in the same niche as an SSRS report). This one part of the overall DataSet needs optimizing. Does SQL Server Analysis services fit this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of in between would be a [TSQL Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910.aspx) that you run on on like and hourly basis to update a semi static report table.

And I think a better term is not bleeding edge current.  The data can be old but it must be accurate.

Comment: Cheers to you, Blam, as well as @Dave.Gugg, who seems to be suggesting the same thing. I tried my hand at writing my first Job within SQL Server Agent and am seeing the benefits!

Comment: Writing the Agent wasn't too painful. I envision someday there being a new entity that I could create under 'Views', perhaps called 'Severed Indexed View' or 'Precompiled View' some such thing that is just as easy to create as a standard View.. and features a simple scheduling interface. Don't get me wrong, I'm quite happy with the more powerful Agent mechanism.. and was able to do what I needed with a single job-step. It just felt like I was grabbing a larger hammer than necessary for the thing I wanted to accomplish. This pushed me to do something new.. so.. thanks for the push!